# enable can interrupt missing in STM32CUBEIDE

Tags: interrupt, can-bus, stm32f0

In every guide I see (e.g. https://www.dailyduino.com/index.php/2020/06/01/stm32-can-bus/) it states that I need to enable can interrupts by going (on the ioc) to pinout and configuration-> connectivity -> CAN ->  NVIC Settings -> enable can interrupt. But when I go there, all I see is "hdmi-cec and can global interrupts / hdmi-cec wake-up interrupt through exti line 27". Clicking on that check-mark does not seem to help my case. The device is acknowledging CAN messages, but the code is not interrupting and I never end up in the callback.

Here is the simplified code:

```
    /* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2021 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
CAN_HandleTypeDef hcan;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim3;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim14;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim16;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim17;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM16_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM14_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM17_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void);
static void MX_CAN_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
CAN_TxHeaderTypeDef TxHeader;
CAN_RxHeaderTypeDef RxHeader;

uint32_t TxMailbox;
uint8_t TxData[8];
uint8_t RxData[8];

uint8_t count = 0;
uint8_t testData;
void HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback(CAN_HandleTypeDef *hcan){
    count++;
    HAL_CAN_GetRxMessage(hcan,CAN_RX_FIFO0,&RxHeader,RxData);
    testData = RxData[0];
}
/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_TIM16_Init();
  MX_TIM14_Init();
  MX_TIM17_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();
  MX_CAN_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan);
  HAL_CAN_ActivateNotification(&hcan, CAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_MSG_PENDING);




TxHeader.DLC = 1;
TxHeader.ExtId = 0;
TxHeader.IDE = CAN_ID_STD;
TxHeader.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
TxHeader.StdId = 0x103;
TxHeader.TransmitGlobalTime = DISABLE;

/*
RxHeader.DLC = 1;
RxHeader.ExtId = 0;
RxHeader.IDE = CAN_ID_STD;
RxHeader.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
RxHeader.StdId = 0x103;
*/

TxData[0] = 0xa7;
//HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan, &TxHeader, TxData, &TxMailbox);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
//      HAL_CAN_GetRxMessage(&hcan,CAN_RX_FIFO0,&RxHeader,RxData);

//    HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan, &TxHeader, TxData, &TxMailbox);
      /* Start the Transmission process */
/*      if (HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan, &TxHeader, TxData, &TxMailbox) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
 */     HAL_Delay(10);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI48;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSI48State = RCC_HSI48_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI48;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief CAN Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_CAN_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN_Init 1 */
  hcan.Instance = CAN;
  hcan.Init.Prescaler = 16;
  hcan.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
  hcan.Init.SyncJumpWidth = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
  hcan.Init.TimeSeg1 = CAN_BS1_1TQ;
  hcan.Init.TimeSeg2 = CAN_BS2_1TQ;
  hcan.Init.TimeTriggeredMode = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.AutoBusOff = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.AutoWakeUp = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.AutoRetransmission = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.ReceiveFifoLocked = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.TransmitFifoPriority = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN_Init 2 */
CAN_FilterTypeDef filterConfig;
        filterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
        filterConfig.FilterBank = 0;
        filterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_RX_FIFO0;
        filterConfig.FilterIdHigh = 0x0000;
        filterConfig.FilterIdLow = 0x0000;
        filterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;
        filterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
        filterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
        filterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
        filterConfig.SlaveStartFilterBank = 14;
  /* USER CODE END CAN_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM3 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_Init 1 */
  htim3.Instance = TIM3;
  htim3.Init.Prescaler = 480-1;
  htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim3.Init.Period = 65535;
  htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim3.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim3, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM14 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM14_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM14_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM14_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM14_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM14_Init 1 */
  htim14.Instance = TIM14;
  htim14.Init.Prescaler = 48000 - 1;
  htim14.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim14.Init.Period = 10- 1;
  htim14.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim14.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim14) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM14_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM14_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM16 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM16_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM16_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM16_Init 1 */
  htim16.Instance = TIM16;
  htim16.Init.Prescaler = 48000 - 1;
  htim16.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim16.Init.Period = 10000 - 1;
  htim16.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim16.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim16.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim16) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM16_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM17 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM17_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM17_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM17_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM17_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM17_Init 1 */
  htim17.Instance = TIM17;
  htim17.Init.Prescaler = 48000 - 1;
  htim17.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim17.Init.Period = 4 - 1;
  htim17.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim17.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim17.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim17) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM17_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM17_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin : VCP_TX_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = VCP_TX_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF1_USART2;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(VCP_TX_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */


/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
      while (1)
      {
      }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

It seems to go through the IRQhandler until it gets to:

```
#if USE_HAL_CAN_REGISTER_CALLBACKS == 1
      /* Call registered callback*/
      hcan->RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback(hcan);
#else
      /* Call weak (surcharged) callback */
      HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback(hcan);
#endif /* USE_HAL_CAN_REGISTER_CALLBACKS */
```

Where it goes into "hcan->RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback(hcan);" instead of the callback "HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback(hcan);"

which I can fix by going to project settings and setting that flag to 0. Unfortunately, now I am getting stuck at a slightly earlier part

```
  /* Receive FIFO 0 full interrupt management ********************************/
  if ((interrupts & CAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_FULL) != 0U)
  {
    if ((rf0rflags & CAN_RF0R_FULL0) != 0U)
    {
      /* Clear FIFO 0 full Flag */
      __HAL_CAN_CLEAR_FLAG(hcan, CAN_FLAG_FF0);

      /* Receive FIFO 0 full Callback */
#if USE_HAL_CAN_REGISTER_CALLBACKS == 1
      /* Call registered callback*/
      hcan->RxFifo0FullCallback(hcan);
#else
      /* Call weak (surcharged) callback */
      HAL_CAN_RxFifo0FullCallback(hcan);
#endif /* USE_HAL_CAN_REGISTER_CALLBACKS */
    }
  }
```

where interrupts is 2 and CAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_FULL is 4, so I dont get to the flag part. Not sure what those two settings mean though.

Comment: What's the exact STM32 chip you are using?

Comment: STM32F042K6T6 LQFP32

Comment: The STM32F042K6T6 and the STM32F103C8T6 in the referenced article have a similar CAN peripheral. However, the STM32F103C8T6 has 4 separate interrupt vectors while the STM32F042K6T6 combines them into a single global one and even shares it with further peripherals (HDMI-CEC, EXTI). It should still work if you check *"HDMI-CEC and CAN global interrupts / HDMI-CEC wake-interrupt through EXTI line 27"*.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that isn't my issue then. Odd that the stm32F0 is issuing ACK to the can message, but the interrupt isn't catching it after setting it up using HAL_CAN_ActivateNotification.

Comment: For further support, you would need to show your code.

Comment: ok, edited to include simplified code

Comment: So you declare and initialize a CAN filter structure but never call `HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter()`? And instead of timer initialization and commented out code, could you rather show `HAL_CAN_MspInit()`?

Comment: Good catch with the config filter, I forgot about that. Running through the code in debug mode, I find that instead of interrupting to "HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsPendingCallback" it seems to be interrupting to "CEC_CAN_IRQHandler". In fact, if I do "HAL_CAN_GetRxMessage" there, I can read the message.

Comment: You're getting close. Step through `HAL_CAN_IRQHandler` to see why `HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback` isn't called.

Comment: It seems to go through the irqhandler until it gets to: 




`#if USE_HAL_CAN_REGISTER_CALLBACKS == 1
      /* Call registered callback*/
      hcan->RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback(hcan);
#else
      /* Call weak (surcharged) callback */
      HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback(hcan);
#endif /* USE_HAL_CAN_REGISTER_CALLBACKS */`

Where it goes into "hcan->RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback(hcan);" instead of the callback "HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback(hcan);"

I updated my question since the formatting looks better there

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem if it goes into `hcan->RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback(hcan)` as it is initialized as `hcan->RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback  =  HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback`. Please revert the flag and see where it goes.

Comment: Interesting. I added a couple more things that I found as I was stepping through the system. Either way it seems to be working now. Not sure which change caused that to happen haha